# I want to a variable value in like in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to put a variable value in like in mongodb

const value = "hello("

db.test.find({keyword:/^${value}/ })
but it wasn't work i don't no how to solve it

and no use $regex...

please help me ....

Answer (score 0):

No need to use substitution this way `${}`. You can use vanilla javascript

```
const pattern = new RegExp("^hello(");
db.test.find({keyword:{'$regex': pattern})
```